# I don't see the inverse kinematics in Blender 3.0?

Tags: inverse-kinematics

Could someone tell me how I add an inverse kinematics object constraint in Blender 3.0? I selected a bone in Pose Mode, then in Properties > Object Constraint Properties > Add Object Constraint, but I don't have the IK option in the menu
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Inverse Kinematic constraint is under the Bone Constraint panel and not the Object Constraint panel.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! @Benus